# PowerShell Search for specific text from results

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I am trying to get a list of saved Wireless Networks on Windows, then for each one, connect to them and tell the network to auto connect. I would only have only one saved network on the machine I would be running this on in normal circumstances. Here's the initial script I have.

```
$wlanprofile = @()
$wlanprofiles = @()
$wlanprofiles = (netsh wlan show profiles) -join "" -replace "Profiles on interface .*User profiles-------------    ","" -split "    All User Profile     : " -replace "All User Profile     : ",""
ForEach($wlanprofile in $wlanprofiles){
netsh wlan connect name=$wlanprofile
Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
netsh wlan set profileparameter name=$wlanprofile connectionmode=auto
}
```

This returns:

```
Hub
dlink
Belkin.5076
```

Only problem is, this relies too much on static text, I wanted to use more smarts to this to get me the same result by way of select-string, pattern, exclude and/or include.

This is what I have so far:

```
$wlanprofiles = (netsh wlan show profiles)
$wlanprofiles | Select-String -Pattern ": "
```

This gives me just line with the ": " in them removing the first few lines e.g.

```
All User Profile     : Hub
All User Profile     : dlink
All User Profile     : Belkin.5076
```

However I want to go one step further and remove **": "** and everything before on each line, e.g. **"*: "**. So I will have only this instead:

```
Hub
dlink
Belkin.5076
```

I think I need to add either an expression or another **Select-String** with exclude or include with wildcards, and maybe a **foreach{}** so this does it for each line, but I am stuck.

Answer (score 0):

```
$wlanprofiles | Select-String -Pattern "(?<=: ).+" | % { $_.Matches[0].Value }
```

The `(?<=: )` removes the `:` from the search results, and the value of the 0th match is then the item you need. Another alternative is:

```
$wlanprofiles | Select-String -Pattern ": (.+)" | % { $_.Matches.Groups[1].Value }
```

which matches the first captured group `(.+)` in each result.

Comment: Remember to use the checkmark (on the left) to mark this as the correct answer.